# A custom object lookup field not visible on visualforce page!

Tags: visualforce, lookup, profile, popup, owner

I have created a custom object with a lookup field NewOwner__c. As per my requirement, I'm using this field in a visualforce case details page's popup to change the case owner. On the case details page(Visualforce), I have provided a custom button 'Change Owner'. When the case owner clicks on 'Change Owner' button, a popup should be displayed which contains an input field(NewOwner__c) that is a lookup to User object. The owner can then select the new owner from the lookup dialog and click change.
[image: Requirement which is visible only to Admin]

But the problem here is, this requirement is met when I view as an Admin. But when logged in as a different user(Case Owner profile), the lookup field is invisible as in second image.
[image: Invisible lookup field when logged in as a user of Case Owner profile]

I have checked all the security access. Case Owner profile has access to  NewOwner__c(Field level security) and also given 'Read' and 'Edit' permissions in the permission set assigned to Case Owner profile.

I have attached the code below:
 
                                              -->

I'm unable to figure out a solution for this. Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is FLS for this NewOwner field for Case owner profile checked for Visible?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Case Owner Profile and see if it has access to `User` object.

When using `lookup` fields, the user's Profile also need to have `read` access to the target object of that `lookup` field, in your case the `User` object.